# Call function from button in django

Tags: django, button, django-urls

On one of my pages I want to display a button, whenever this button is clicked I want to display the following in my display "Button clicked".

However the following message displays in my console.""GET /account/all-plan/?print_btn=Click HTTP/1.1" 200 5025"

This is my view

```
def print_from_button(request):
if(request.GET.get('print_btn')):
    print('Button clicked')
return HttpResponse('testklik')
```

html

```
<form method="get">
   <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="print_btn">
</form>
```

and url in urls.py

```
path('all-plan/print_from_button', views.print_from_button, name='print_from_button'),
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction, I cannot find what I am missing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have to URLs:

1. `/account/all-plan/`
2. `/account/all-plan/print_from_button`

In the first URL you are creating a `<form>` which uses the `GET` method, but no [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action) attribute is specified. The result is that your form submits to the same URL as the current page (first URL). This can be seen as your console print says it's using the first URL with an extra [GET parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method).

In order to get your form to use the correct URL you need to specify the `action` attribute with the correct URL:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url "app_name:print_from_button" %}">
  ...
</form>
```